# How to assign infinite and negative colSums values as 0?

Tags: r

I want to ensure that `colSums(mat)` is **finite** and **non-negative**. The `mat` was derived from a dataframe.

```
mat <- apply(as.matrix(df), 2, as.numeric)
rownames(mat) <- rownames(df)
rownames(mat) <- make.names(rownames(mat), unique=TRUE) # Keep only unique indices

mat[, colSums(sapply(.SD, is.infinite))]  <- 0
mat[, colSums(sapply(.SD, <- 0))]  <- 0
```

Traceback:

```
> mat[, colSums(sapply(.SD, is.infinite))]  <- 0
Error in base::colSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
> mat[, colSums(sapply(.SD, <- 0))]  <- 0
Error: unexpected assignment in "mat[, columns (sapply(.SD, <-"
```

Purpose (downstream):

```
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("edgeR")

library(edgeR)

cpm <- cpm(mat)
```

^ that returned:

```
Error in cpm.default(mat) : 
  library sizes should be finite and non-negative
```

Data:

```
dput(df[1:20,1:20])
structure(list(TCGA.BQ.7051.11A = c("57.4382", "233.2193", "18.244", 
"1928.9092", "0.3041", "16482.7822", "1150.8932", "5.7773", "5.1691", 
"619.0802", "7.9057", "680.8058", "0", "0", "3.3447", "0.3041", 
"114.3292", "1111.9726", "2636.564", "2320.9426"), TCGA.DZ.6132.11A = c("70.6982", 
"78.683", "5.6652", "173.5022", "0.3147", "36833.3219", "1489.626", 
"10.7009", "1.8884", "712.553", "8.4978", "709.4057", "0", "0", 
"2.8326", "0.3147", "93.7901", "1058.1286", "1706.1616", "2334.0517"
), TCGA.CZ.4864.11A = c("12.9899", "658.051", "7.335", "2416.7342", 
"0", "31651.9804", "837.9322", "3.1436", "4.5407", "575.9693", 
"16.7656", "752.707", "0", "0", "3.1436", "0.3493", "214.4604", 
"1133.0772", "1635.6968", "2495.634"), TCGA.KN.8426.11A = c("47.5866", 
"7.0464", "13.212", "279.0018", "0.2936", "35180.2554", "644.7446", 
"8.2208", "0.2936", "684.0869", "6.1656", "1127.4222", "0", "0", 
"4.1104", "0", "142.983", "1105.1086", "2037.5807", "2294.7739"
), TCGA.CZ.5982.11A = c("11.257", "601.2091", "16.6771", "3387.5714", 
"0", "19067.2504", "720.4503", "0.4169", "7.0878", "513.6544", 
"7.0878", "611.6323", "0", "0", "1.2508", "0", "200.1251", "949.3433", 
"2129.2474", "2382.7392"), TCGA.A4.A4ZT.11A = c("33.5985", "6.8336", 
"33.5985", "261.2826", "0.5695", "13559.3697", "595.6618", "4.5557", 
"1.7084", "901.4652", "10.8199", "1305.2169", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "112.7543", "879.256", "1400.3178", "2940.1548"), TCGA.CZ.5468.11A = c("49.1104", 
"2.7165", "4.7538", "140.5806", "0.3396", "35977.7114", "1595.5857", 
"7.1307", "0.6791", "565.0255", "6.1121", "1053.6503", "0", "0", 
"1.0187", "0.6791", "97.4533", "1427.5042", "1459.4228", "2766.0441"
), TCGA.BQ.5894.11A = c("9.4012", "404.1695", "4.5652", "2753.2831", 
"0.6087", "21390.7875", "1095.0316", "0.913", "5.4782", "593.1675", 
"15.5216", "714.6009", "0", "0", "1.2174", "0", "222.1715", "1015.2933", 
"1738.7202", "2698.0142"), TCGA.B0.5699.11A = c("24.3902", "312.8518", 
"19.6998", "2229.8311", "0", "26106.3884", "616.3227", "1.4071", 
"5.1595", "506.0976", "6.0976", "713.8837", "0", "0", "3.2833", 
"0", "119.137", "1039.8687", "1924.015", "2181.5197"), TCGA.KL.8339.11A = c("55.0631", 
"190.1558", "7.8662", "3129.6608", "0.342", "21571.2208", "1032.5189", 
"2.394", "5.1301", "671.3596", "8.2082", "736.3409", "0.342", 
"0", "2.052", "0.342", "186.7358", "1427.5369", "820.1326", "2612.2488"
), TCGA.CZ.5988.11A = c("20.1192", "456.1949", "18.1441", "1703.9554", 
"0", "17107.7242", "542.7683", "8.2945", "9.3313", "513.2193", 
"12.9601", "755.3136", "0", "0", "2.592", "0", "114.5671", "1145.6713", 
"1835.6661", "2131.156"), TCGA.CZ.5461.11A = c("17.0523", "84.4762", 
"22.9219", "378.0465", "0.2575", "26237.1798", "666.7954", "1.8028", 
"1.2877", "572.0173", "3.0906", "1308.8661", "0", "0", "0.2575", 
"0.2575", "142.9399", "1435.5805", "1839.4179", "1916.1677"), 
    TCGA.CJ.6030.11A = c("20.2697", "249.42", "5.8005", "1017.0012", 
    "0.29", "17652.3173", "1327.1462", "2.0302", "3.1903", "565.5452", 
    "6.6705", "596.5777", "0", "0", "0.8701", "3.7703", "95.9977", 
    "1146.4617", "1734.6288", "2736.949"), TCGA.B8.5549.11A = c("21.2237", 
    "4.7261", "19.5797", "215.8933", "0", "21086.1406", "422.3141", 
    "12.4905", "1.0127", "574.5633", "13.8408", "1016.1195", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "146.8478", "1111.3174", "2287.4504", 
    "2078.1501"), TCGA.CW.5587.11A = c("19.4004", "331.9224", 
    "12.3457", "1010.4515", "0.3527", "18024.8677", "569.3122", 
    "8.1129", "8.1129", "586.2434", "8.1129", "934.0388", "0", 
    "0", "3.1746", "0", "157.3192", "1148.5009", "2105.1146", 
    "2099.4709"), TCGA.CZ.5987.11A = c("20.0787", "129.6975", 
    "5.4267", "181.5873", "0", "58305.2015", "955.0943", "3.256", 
    "3.7987", "441.1884", "8.14", "565.4592", "0.5427", "0", 
    "0.5427", "0", "110.1614", "1111.9251", "1871.6592", "1728.3951"
    ), TCGA.CJ.5677.11A = c("15.5786", "254.3668", "12.0087", 
    "1445.4185", "0", "27034.1412", "1054.2213", "7.278", "6.5502", 
    "514.9199", "6.9141", "666.6667", "0.3639", "0.7278", "6.5502", 
    "0", "150.655", "1131.7322", "1821.6885", "2065.1383"), TCGA.CZ.5470.11A = c("30.6748", 
    "12.2699", "18.1382", "161.115", "0.2667", "42664.8866", 
    "508.669", "6.9352", "1.3337", "479.3278", "10.136", "1396.6391", 
    "0", "0", "1.6004", "0.2667", "144.3051", "1090.9576", "1129.3678", 
    "2873.833"), TCGA.B2.5636.11A = c("23.7973", "330.8851", 
    "11.3845", "1674.058", "0", "29790.2387", "716.1219", "15.7914", 
    "7.3448", "600.0734", "12.119", "646.3459", "0", "0", "2.2035", 
    "0", "159.7503", "1049.2104", "2017.6276", "2118.2519"), 
    TCGA.CJ.5676.11A = c("21.6856", "246.2389", "10.7461", "580.697", 
    "0.307", "28766.8161", "1339.2693", "1.8422", "7.3687", "507.8293", 
    "10.4391", "590.4206", "0", "0", "2.1492", "0", "122.1983", 
    "1136.9358", "1914.9524", "2034.6945")), row.names = c("A1BG", 
"A1CF", "A2BP1", "A2LD1", "A2ML1", "A2M", "A4GALT", "A4GNT", 
"AAA1", "AAAS", "AACSL", "AACS", "AADACL2", "AADACL3", "AADACL4", 
"AADAC", "AADAT", "AAGAB", "AAK1", "AAMP"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the goal, there’s no need to use `sapply()` or `data.table::.SD`; you can just do:

```
mat[, is.infinite(colSums(mat)) | colSums(mat) < 0] <- 0
```

(I don’t think this actually affects any columns in your example data, though.)

Comment: The code works fine but I still get `Error in cpm.default(mat) : 
  library sizes should be finite and non-negative` when I run `cpm <- cpm(mat)`.

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/edgeR/versions/3.14.0/topics/cpm